# Typescript - if conditrional inside a map

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, if-statement

I am mapping a subset of user data to an object of a refined data set. Inside the map i want to check if a variable is null or undefined, and if yes, then to set this variable to a placeholder value.

The issue I am facing is that declaring an if statement inside the map is causing an error, but even though a map can have an index as a parameter, how can we use it functionally with a conditional Statement? Any insight most appreciated.

```
return this.UserService.search(url)
.map((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    data.result = <any> data.result.map((user, index) => ({
        // if statement causing error here
        if(user.name === null || user.name === undefined){
            // error with this if condition
        },
        id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        type: user.type,
        password: user.password,
    }));
    return data;
}).map(data => ({
    meta: { totalItems: data.size },
    data: data.result,
}));
```

Comment: What error? And you aren't returning from inside the inner map.

Comment: Certainly you can use `if` statements inside mapping functions. Please provide some sample input and desired output, otherwise it's not clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: please see the code in the original post. I am attempted to return the data set of {id name type and password} but id first like to check the value of type before setting it.

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to use an object literal as the return type, but naturally, an `if` statement (or any statement) can't be inside object literal syntax.

So instead, define a function body, which also uses curly braces, and put your code inside with an explicit `return` statement.

```
// Starts function body instead of single expression-v
data.result = <any> data.result.map((user, index) => {

    if (some_condition) {
       return "some value"; // The object?
    } else {
       return "other value"; // A different object?
    }
  /*
    // I assume these are to be used in the object you return
    id: user.id,
    name: user.name,
    type: user.type,
    password: user.password, 
  */
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can express conditions in literal maps, but it is somewhat ugly.

```
return {
 a: 1,
 ...(some_condition && {
  b: 1,
 })
};
```

Comment: how do user `if else`

Comment: if else: `{ a:1, ...(some_condition ? {b:1} : {c:1})};`

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you can't do that with JUST a map.
however you could follow it up with a filter() function:

```
const newArray = oldArray.map((value, index) => condition ? value : null).filter(v => v);
```

you basicaly iterate over each item and then return the value or null depending on your condition.
Now once you have the map you just filter it by removing the null values from the array.

Notice that the original array is not altered and a new one is returned.
thanks for the idea @user8897421 for the idea. i just wanted to turn it into a one liner.