# Typescript if conditional before returning a new object

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, if-statement

I have written a piece of code which will map the value of a data set to a new object.

I would like to check one of the variables in the dataset before assigning it to the new object variable. To do this I will use an if conditional. How can I achieve this using a map in Typescript. The following code will return an error if I try to compile.

If I attempt to do an if conditional at the console.log line, it will only affect the first item in the data set.

```
return this.UserService.search(url)
.map((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    data.result = <any> data.result.map((user, index) => ({
        // if statement causing error here
        if(user.name === null || user.name === undefined){
            // error with this if condition
        },
        id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        type: user.type,
        password: user.password,
    }));
    return data;
}).map(data => ({
    meta: { totalItems: data.size },
    data: data.result,
}));
```

Comment: basic javascript syntax, you are returning an object, you can't have an `if` statement in an object like that - I mean, what is the property name?

Comment: yes I cannot use an if inside a map. but, before mapping, I would like to check the user.name fore null values, and if it is null, add a place holder name. something like user.name = 'jaromanda'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript - if conditrional inside a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619404/typescript-if-conditrional-inside-a-map)

Answer (score 0):

Basic syntax issue. Change your map code as follows

```
data.result = <any> data.result.map((user, index) => {
  if (user.name === null || user.name === undefined) {

  }
  return {
    id: user.id,
    name: user.name,
    type: user.type,
    password: user.password,
  }
});
```

alternatively, use a ternary operator

```
data.result = <any> data.result.map((user, index) => ({
    id: user.id,
    name: (user.name === null || user.name === undefined) ? "???" : user.name,
    type: user.type,
    password: user.password,
}));
```

Not sure what needs to be where I've put `"???"` - because you haven't shown what to do when the condition is true

Comment: My guess is no error, probably some tslint warning that looks like an error. Or `user` is `null` or `undefined` instead of property on it

Comment: sorry, I inadvertently put a space in `=>` in the first bit of code - small typo on my part which should've been picked up by the different error being displayed - the second piece of code should work fine, if not, then typescript actually sux

Comment: the ternary operator works perfectly.  i am new to functional programming and ternary operators. thank you for expanding my knowledge and providing a solution to this problem, most appreciated.

Comment: the space did not make an issue. I believe its because my return type should be an observable and note a pure object

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add a return type to the UserService.search method. That way you'll have code completion and the compiler will be happy.

```
interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    type: string;
    password: string;
}
class UserService {
    async search(url: string): Promise<User[]> {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        return response.json();
    }
}

class Foo {
    constructor(private UserService: UserService) {}

    async bar() {
        const users = await this.UserService.search("/users");
        return users.map((user) => {
            if (!user.name) {
                // error...
            }
        })
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANz6EhzUTnphSgDmThZGACeABw7IuPEP2YFRcdOgDuAeyhlJ3PkwC%20uBABtF6NJigBlaADdgSHHOSLhIBJIhwoCABYAKSlCGnNoyAJTkAApQqtTAmAA8GNAA2gC6AHwOgoIIqiBcyFAQ6KJ5mMgAvE7KcMBgyDAQYD7%20gaEC2QRFYAEghcWl%20RAAdABW6Hm%207Y76%20gbGSsgAYqqqWYS5%20dyUCGDqvqI81nCQZtBWULZI5EmWNnYQoThzgs6uyLSeU%20udmwWU5lMVTgNTqQm8cWGtwuVxGmE8LQARAB6AHQdCI6adLpNXrINFQdDDahwUS%20fzmJ4VTJ4bHZYAwZC%20ACEBOGrHYT1pdOxyORyGg0SgwxFjjp%20nFoRmuH0QA).